# Rails 3.2 group count with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, kaminari

I am trying to display in my a table with most popular tag words, ordered by the count of impression. Then add kaminari to paginate through the records.

in my controller I tried:

```
@tag_answers = Tag.group(:content).page(params[:page]).order("count_all DESC").count
```

and in my view:

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <th>Tag</th>
     <th>Count</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @tag_answers.each do |tag_content, tag_count| %>
      <tr>
         <td> <%= tag_content %> </td>
         <td> <%= tag_count %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= paginate @tag_answers %>
```

but i am getting the following error

```
undefined method `current_page' for #<ActiveSupport::OrderedHash:0x000001031b8678>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
@tag_answers = Tag.group(:content).select('content, COUNT(*) as count').order("count DESC").page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Yep it worked! thanks! For answer sake, in the view I had to change the each block with `<% @tag_answers.each do |tag| %>` or `<% @tag_answers.each_with_index |tag, index| %>` and to display the count `<%= tag.count %>`. Very good! Also is it SQL safe?

Comment: yea, using raw sql is dangerous, but the type of the result should be ActiveRecord::Relation instead of ActiveSupport::OrderedHash to use pagination. By the way it seems to be hard to inject the code in this raw sql.